# Example of using ActiveMQ on asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, activemq-classic

I am trying to find an example of how to use Apache ActiveMQ on an asp.net (C#) website. As far as I have been able to figure out, you have to use REST webservices, but as I am a newbie with regards to both ActiveMQ and REST webservices, I could really use an example on how to do it.

What I need to do is set up a queue on a broker and create a message producer and consumer that can communicate using the broker queue.

I have searched long and hard on the internet, but I have only been able to find examples on how to do this using either command line commands or WinForms.

Does anyone have a link to a good and thorough example of using ActiveMQ on a asp.net website??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you do not have to use REST.
here is examples of how to do it with tcp, with NMS (.NET client for ActiveMQ) .
to not copy paste here code available i gave you direct links to code, do not hesitate

http://activemq.apache.org/nms/examples.html

http://activemq.apache.org/nms/nms-simple-asynchronous-consumer-example.html

full example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ActiveMQ-in-NET-Sample-9406441a

http://www.wi1.uni-muenster.de/pi/lehre/ss11/EAI/tutorials/tutorial_jms_net.html
https://remark.wordpress.com/articles/messaging-with-net-and-activemq/

Comment: Am I completely off track here - or are non of the examples you have linked to web forms/sites?? As far as I can tell they all send their output to consoles. 

I know they can most likely be adopted for web use, but as mentioned I am completely new to this, and really need an example written for a web form/site to get me started.

Comment: examples are sending their output to consoles but you cann add your business and do what you want with these messages and in general it is good to start with logging messages to validate the consuming